# preg_replace issue in php

Tags: php, regex

I have been stuck with a regex and I tried everything I could think about to solve it, in vain.
I have a text with different kinds of "tags" inside, for example : [[Category:Animals]].The word after "Category:" can be different (like "Category:School") and that's why I want to match "[[Category: ... ]]" to remove that tag from the text. When I try my code on phpliveregex.com, it works, but once uploaded on the server, it doesn't work.

```
$text = '[[Category:Animals]]';
$pattern = '/\[\[Category:(.*?)\]\]/';
$intro = preg_replace($pattern, "", $text, $count);
```

When I display the result of $count to check the match, the result is NULL. I have tried different regex and still no match...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: show a sample of $text... and $count isn't changed by preg. that's where YOU specify how many replacements should be done. if $count is null, then you're passing in an undefined variable, and PHP is PROBABLY "politely" changing it to a 0, meaning you're telling php to do NO replacements. the count is actually argument #5, which you're not providing.

Comment: Right, I forgot to provide the sample text, sorry. I checked the php manual and added "-1" as the limit as you comment suggested and it now works ! It was just me who didn't read the manual correctly and wasted an hour ... Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$count` is supposed to be [5th parameter in `preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). So use:

```
$intro = preg_replace($pattern, "", $text, -1, $count);
```

4th parameter is actually `limit` that sets **maximum possible replacements**.